# How to make a class where one attribute is a generated list of the attributes of another list in the class?

Tags: json, flutter, list, dart, class

I have a class of prices in a store. It does not accept `price_range` as an input but I want it to produce a list of all the prices of the products for itself.

```
{
    "mall": 
    [
        {
            "store_id": 1,
            "price_range": [],
            "products":
            [
                {
                    "product_id": 1,
                    "price": 9.99
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "store_id": 2,
            "price_range": [],
            "products":
            [
                {
                    "product_id": 1,
                    "price": 45.99
                },
                {
                    "product_id": 2,
                    "price": 25.99
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible for price_range to have the prices of the products?
For in this case:

store1 can have `price_range = [9.99]` and
store2 can have `price_range = [45.99, 25.99]`?

I have appended my model at the bottom. I tried to use `this._price_range = product_model.map((element) => double.parse(element.price));`. Not sure yet if it is able to create the list of prices. I have removed the ProductModel class to make it shorter.

```
class Mall {
  late List<mallModel> _mall;
  List<mallModel> get mall => _mall;

  Mall({required mall}){
    this._mall = mall;
  }

  Mall.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['contents'] != null) {
    _mall = <MallModel>[];
      json['mall'].forEach((v) {
        _mall!.add(MallModel.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
}

class StoreModel {
  int? store_id;
  late List<ProductModel> _product_model;
  List<ProductModel> get product_model =>_product_model;

  late List<double> _price_range;
  List<double> get price_range => _price_range;

  StoreModel(
      {required store_id;
        required product_model}){
    this._product_model = product_model;
    this._price_range = product_model.map((element) => double.parse(element.price));
  }

  StoreModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    store_id= json['store_id'];
    if (json['products'] != null) {
      _product_model = <ProductModel>[];
      json['products'].forEach((v) {
        _product_model.add(Product.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
   _price_range = [];
  }
}
```

When I try to run my app, I am getting this error
`LateInitializationError: Field '_price_range@22053741' has not been initialized.`

Comment: You have to initiate `_price_range` in `StoreModel.fromJson` as well

Comment: I tried that but it only returns `[]`. I updated my code.

Comment: dont forget to add `.toList()` everytime you use `.map()` because it returns an iterable. also why not create an emptylist instead of using late e.g. `List<double> _price_range = [];`

Comment: i haven't thought of creating an empty list. How exactly can you do that? Is it still an attribute of class StoreModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initiate `_price_range` in `StoreModel.fromJson`

```
class StoreModel {
  int? store_id;
  late List<ProductModel> _product_model;
  List<ProductModel> get product_model =>_product_model;

  late List<double> _price_range;
  List<double> get price_range => _price_range;

  StoreModel(
      {required this.store_id,
        required product_model}){
    this._product_model = product_model;
    this._price_range = product_model.map((element) => double.parse(element.price)).toList();
  }

  StoreModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    store_id= json['store_id'];
     _product_model = <ProductModel>[];
    if (json['products'] != null) {
      json['products'].forEach((v) {
        _product_model.add(Product.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    this._price_range = product_model.map((element) => double.parse(element.price)).toList();
  }
}
```

I hope this helps!.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting `LateInitializationError` is because you are using variable `_price_range` before initializing it.

You can consider making it `nullable` instead.

Change:

```
late List<double> _price_range;
```

To

```
List<double>? _price_range;
```